# mac os alternative for Linux/KDE Skrooge budgeting app

Tags: finance, productivity

I've been using KDE Skrooge budgeting app for a few years but now I switched to mac os.

I'm looking for app similar to Skrooge and I'd like it to be / have:

- open source (not that important)
- desktop app (no online web app)

GNU Cash is a no-go.

Why GNU Cash is a no-go recommendation?

This is off course my opinion based on many years of using Skrooge but trying it for a while I didn't find it as good as Skrooge.

- having several categories in Skrooge (bills, food, etc) after importing data to GNU Cash I ended up with as many accounts as I had in Skrooge. In Skrooge I was using following accounts (regular bank account, pre-paid card, and wallet - it was implemented as my feature request!). An item can be added to any category to any account - so for example at the end of month you can see how much you spent on food across all accounts
- The interface is for me kind of 'raw'; (treat is as very subjective opinion)
- GNU Cash couldn't handle the following scenario: week ago, when I usually deal with the budget, I enter all bills and prices, or bank accounts. By accident the food category (let's say $X) landed not in wallet account (as I prefer to use 'real' money), but my main bank account. In Skrooge it'd only required to update account field, but in GNU Cash (after importing data) I ended up with messed up data that was no longer 'in-sync').

What I like in Skrooge?

- budget feature and comparing real and planned budget
- transfer from one account to the other (like drawing money from cash machine)
- no need for online account
- the author, or one of them (Stephane Mankowski), implements a feaure request in a very short period of time if he finds it useful. It's not a do it know for free!, dude, or I'll kill you! As far I remember he implemented at least 2 (TWO) feature requests.

Why Skrooge for Mac is a no-go?

The docs says that the app for Mac is for only testing purposes <s>so I took it for granted</s>. If it is not that bad, please let me know.

Mac version is only available from macports. As Skrooge is a KDE app, in order to install it requires additional KDE dependencies.

Comment: Is there a particular reason GNUCash is a no-go? Knowing the reason it doesn't work for you will help others answer the question.

Comment: What's wrong with their OS X version? http://skrooge.org/macos_installation

Comment: Question has been updated. If Software Recommendations is a better place for this kind of questions, I can move it there, but I'd like to avoid cross-posting.